# How do I check for error message popup in browser using webdriver?

Tags: testing, error-handling, webdriver, testng

I have login form on website,
 i want to make automatic testcase for this scenario:
i give phone number but no password:
[image: tt]

How do I test selenium to give me expected red error message popup?
What function is in selenium api to check for it? I did not find it!

EDIT: or maybe my expected thing to happen should be "stay on same page"?

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific function like that. Find out what is the xpath for that red colored text. Then you can create a web element using that xpath and check whether it is visible and what is the text value of that element, and assert on that.

Answer (score 0):

As an example:
You first define the error message `WebElement` as `messageElement`

You may locate the element like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("error-message"))
```

Then you may get the error message text using this:

```
messageElement.getText());
```

Once you get the text you can then validate it with the expected text.

```
Assert.assertEquals(actualMessage, expectedMessage);
```

PS:
From snap, it doesn't seem to be another pop-up so no need to use switch to alert etc.